# phpfox4.0.6 create postition and relocate position

Tags: phpfox

I am working on theme and want to create new position in theme and move existing position to other location.

So that I easily assign blocks to it.

but in 4 version I don't know how to do that. there is only a html code from admincp , when I try to change theme default template , it doesn't reflect any changes .

any kind suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got solution it's not upgrade safe but yes it's working for me

There are two files where we need to add code.

Adding block and customization in blocks position
phpfox\PF.Src\Core\View.php
phpfox\PF.Src\Core\View\ Functions.php
Here you can add position location , take example of “right” in code.

Code works for me but still want any upgrade safe solution.

Comment: why you need additional position? it is not good idea to change core, only to introduce a position. Edit theme instead of editing core files, did you enabled DnD mode?

Comment: Yes I enable DND but all position are not there , only few postion are using. I am creating new position because of my design requirement.